# Mount multiple volumes by label without repeating the command?

Tags: bash, mount, macos

I have this on-liner:
`diskutil mount VOL1 && diskutil mount VOL2 && diskutil mount VOL3`

But I would like to not repeat the command 'diskutil mount' with an in-line array.
I am trying to find a solution in the style of: `diskutil mount {VOL1,VOL2,VOL3}`

And how is this written with xargs?

Comment: Why not putting this in a script file and executing that instead?

Answer (score 6):

According to the `diskutil` [man page](https://ss64.com/osx/diskutil.html), the `mount` command is explicitly designed for mounting a single volume (emphasis mine):

> mount [readOnly] [-mountPoint path] device
>
> **Mount a single volume**. If readOnly is specified, then the file system is mounted read-only, even if the volume's underlying file system and/or device and/or media supports writing; even the super-user may not write to it; this is the same as the rdonly option to mount (8). If a -mountPoint is specified, then that path, rather than the standard path of /Volumes/VolumeName, will be used as the view into the volume file
> content; a directory at that path must already exist.

This means you can't do the simple `diskutil mount {VOL1,VOL2,Vol3}` which would expand to `diskutil mount VOL1 VOL2 Vol3`. However, you can indeed do it with `xargs` as you suggested:

```
printf '%s\n' {VOL1,VOL2,VOL3} | xargs -I{} diskutil mount {}
```

Or with a simple loop:

```
for i in {VOL1,VOL2,VOL3}; do diskutil mount "$i"; done
```

Comment: Thanks! The loop still does look easier than the xargs solution. Is it possible to make the xargs version less complex?

Comment: The for loop works directly from the prompt, but not as an alias.
This will only mount the last item, 'VOL3': 
`alias mount="for i in {VOL1,VOL2,VOL3}; do diskutil mount \"$i\"; done"`

Comment: @Kasam just define a function instead of an alias. `mymount() { for i in {VOL1,VOL2,VOL3}; do diskutil mount "$i"; done; }` Also see last sentence here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Aliases.html - and redefining `mount` like you do with the alias does not look like a good idea ;)

Comment: @Kasam Instead of an alias you need a function or better yet a script. Write that for loop in a text file. Name it something like "mount-all". Save it to a folder named "bin" in your home folder. Add "$HOME/bin" to your PATH. Now you can run `mount-all` and have all your disks mounted. Don't create scripts or functions or aliases with the same names as critical utilities like "mount" or "cd" or "ls". Aliases are OK for command line arguments but not for entire scripts like the for loop

Comment: Thanks for the idea about defining a function. It was a bad example of me with using 'mount' as the alias name. I am off course using another name. Strangely the loop worked without defining a function when using single quotes around the whole alias.

Comment: I got the double quotes version to work as well. I had internal double quotes escaped, but that was not enough, `$` also needed to be escaped.